# The argument type 'Future<dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future<Object>?'

Tags: flutter, dart, datagrid, syncfusion

The Error:

lib/pages/view_page.dart:90:21: Error: The argument type 'Future' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Future?'
because 'dynamic' is nullable and 'Object' isn't.

- 'Future' is from 'dart:async'.
- 'Object' is from 'dart:core'.
  future: generateEmployeeList(),

The codes which have a specific error

```
@override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
              title: Text('Syncfusion flutter datagrid'),
            ),
            body: FutureBuilder<Object> (
                future: generateEmployeeList(),
                builder: (context, data) {
                  return data.hasData
                      ? SfDataGrid(
                          source: employeeDataSource,
                          columns: _columns,
                          columnWidthMode: ColumnWidthMode.fill)
                      : Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          strokeWidth: 2,
                          value: 0.8,
                        ));
                }));
      }
```

Future codes:

```
        Future<dynamic> generateEmployeeList() async {
            // Give your PHP URL. It may be online URL o local host URL.
            // Follow the steps provided in the below KB to configure the mysql using
            // XAMPP and get the local host php link,
            ///
            var url = "my_url";
            final response = await http.get(Uri.parse(url));
            var list = json.decode(response.body);
        
            // Convert the JSON to List collection.
            List<Employee> _employees =
                await list.map<Employee>((json) => Employee.fromJson(json)).toList();
            employeeDataSource = EmployeeDataSource(_employees);
            return _employees;
          }
```

Question: How can I assign The argument type 'Future' to the parameter type 'Future?'

Answer (score 0):

The error is because you have `FutureBuilder<Object>`, but `generateEmployeeList()` has a return type of `Future<dynamic>`. Type `dynamic` can be `null`, but `Object` can't be `null`.

Since you are returning a `List<Employee>` value from the future, solve the problem like this:

```
body: FutureBuilder<List<Employee>>
```

And then:

```
Future<List<Employee>> generateEmployeeList() async {
  ...
  return Future.value(_employees);
}
```